# Cannot convert from Repository to IRepository UOW Repository pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am trying a MVC project with repository pattern and unit of work.

The following is from my InitOfWork

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<User> UserRepository { get; }
    void Save();
}
```

and this is from UnitOfWork

```
public class UnitOfWork:IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private JNContext context = new JNContext();
    private bool disposed = false;


    private IRepository<User> userRepository;
    public IRepository<User> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.userRepository == null)
            {
                this.userRepository = new Repository<User>(this.context);
            }

            return this.userRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }}
```

The following line in UnitOfWork generates the error 'Cannot implicitly convert from Repository to IRepository

```
this.userRepository = new Repository<User>(this.context);
```

What am I missing. I cannot find an answer and I am stuck the entire day.

Comment: are you sure, that Repository implements IRepository?

Comment: @wheeler : No, it wasn't. I was having **public class Repository<TEntity>where TEntity:class**. Do I need to implement **IRepository** ? Is it posible with Dependency Injection

Comment: Yes you need to implement `IRepository`. in `Repository`. Compiler can't figure it out without this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   IQueryable<T> Entities { get; }
   void Remove(T entity);
   void Add(T entity);
}
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    private IDbSet<T> _dbSet => _dbContext.Set<T>();
    public IQueryable<T> Entities => _dbSet;
    public GenericRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Found a good article about it here: https://medium.com/@utterbbq/c-unitofwork-and-repository-pattern-305cd8ecfa7a